# Sticky header recyclerview with custom view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, stickyrecycleview

I am working with a financial management application, which has a list of holy transactions that are grouped by date, currently I want to add the header as milestone, I have read many examples on github but no mail Which hospital is suitable. Someone please help.

Answer (score -1):

@Mạnh Duy Nguyễn this may solve your problem 
https://github.com/paetztm/recycler_view_headers. 
 You also create a custom header for your application.